# Windows 7 hangs while loading desktop

Tags: windows-7, freeze, desktop

I am facing a weird problem. My computer hangs while loading the desktop, and only the background shows up; no icons or bars load. If I power the system on and off about 4-6 times, I may be able to use it normally.

The desktop loads normally after rebooting or in safe mode; this only occurs when I start the system normally. I've tried several things to fix it, such as removing all start-up items, but it still doesn't solve the problem.  What should I do?

I found three major errors in Event Viewer:

> Source:        Microsoft-Windows-DistributedCOM 
> Level:         Error
>
> DCOM got error "1084" attempting to start the service WSearch with arguments "" in order to run the server: `{7D096C5F-AC08-4F1F-BEB7-5C22C517CE39}`
>
> ---
>
> Source:        Microsoft-Windows-DistributedCOM 
> Level:         Error 
> DCOM got error "1084" attempting to start the service WSearch with arguments "" in order to run the server: `{7D096C5F-AC08-4F1F-BEB7-5C22C517CE39}`
>
> ---
>
> Source:   Service Control Manager 
> Level:        Error 
> The Network List Service service depends on the Network Location Awareness service which failed to start because of the following error: The dependency service or group failed to start.

Comment: Why didn't the Network Location Awareness service start?  If it's because another service it depends on didn't start, then why didn't that service start?  Additionally: Have you tested your disks?  How long have you let it sit "hung"?  Do you, or have you in the past, had any network resources mapped?  Have you tried booting it with no external USB devices (aside from mouse/kb) plugged in?

Comment: Yes, I have test disks, everything is ok. I left it for almost 2 hours, it is still hang. No network mapped. Well I will try USB issue

Comment: `If I power the system on and off about 4-6 times, I may be able to use it normally.`   This is the most telling piece of information (which most people will easily miss). If this problem is intermittent and rebooting over and over again can cause it to suddenly work without you making any actual changes (i.e., nothing *should* have changed between the times it works and times it doesn’t work), then it is likely a hardware issue. Try a [memory test](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gD1im.png)) and check the drive’s SMART data.

Comment: Is explorer.exe failing to load properly? The next time you have no icons: Ctrl + Alt + Del, Task Manager, Processes tab, End Process for 'explorer.exe' (if it exists), switch to Applications tab, New Task, 'explorer.exe'

Answer (score 0):

It's good you cleared out your start up items, but there is another way to start items with your PC - Next time you load up Windows successfully, go to your task scheduler - Look through and there is probably something starting up as your PC does (I had an Asus service trying to start and it caused error messages on each boot).

Also, it is possible it's a service which you don't want. Type `services.msc` into the search bar and see if you can find the failing service and disable or delay it.

Answer (score 0):

WSearch is messing up
try disable Windows Search in services.msc 
you might lose the search in explorer but what the hey, when the pc dont start then its better than nothing

Answer (score 0):

Create a new login if you have access to safe mode - Login with new user and copy your stuff over.

Answer (score -3):

Why don't you test a linux live on your system to see if its a really hardware issue or OS's.... If it will appear your OS is really gone made  than there is nothing best to do with WINDOWS than re-installing the system.  Beleive or not Windows are enemy of old hardware...as your hardware getting older you have to come across more and more issues every mornings.

Comment: How would this help diagnose the problem? While a Linux Live medium would probably work, how would that help fix the Windows issue?